# Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm executing this database script, but I have a problem as below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

COMMIT

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

DECLARE @v sql_variant 
SET @v = N'0: unknown, 1: checkin, 2: checkout, 3: staff-checkin, 4: staff-checkout, 5: lunch-out, 6: lunch-in, 7: others'

EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', @v, N'SCHEMA', N'dbo', N'TABLE', N'GB_FingerprintCommand', N'COLUMN', N'Command'
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.GB_FingerprintCommand SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO

COMMIT

SELECT 
    Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.GB_FingerprintCommand', 'Object', 'ALTER') AS ALT_Per, 
    Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.GB_FingerprintCommand', 'Object', 'VIEW 
DEFINITION') AS View_def_Per, 
    Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.GB_FingerprintCommand', 'Object', 'CONTROL') AS Contr_Per
```

> Msg 15135, Level 16, State 8, Procedure sp_addextendedproperty, Line 37 [Batch Start Line 20]
>   Object is invalid. Extended properties are not permitted on 'dbo.GB_FingerprintCommand.Command', or the object does not exist.
>
> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Cannot find the object "dbo.GB_FingerprintCommand" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
>
> Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
>   The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: GO can be used in this case. Triet, please try before first transaction SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE and GO's after all commits.

Comment: It says it can't find the object, or you don't have access.  I suggest confirming that the schema for table "GB_FingerprintCommand" is "dbo".